# How can I find Palindrome numbers in a range using Powershell on VSCode?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to find out the Palindrome numbers within a range using Powershell on VSCode. However I am not getting the expected output.

```
Clear-Host;
Write-Verbose -Message "This script is for checking Palindrome numbers between a range" -Verbose;
Write-Host "Please enter the range of numbers" -ForegroundColor Cyan;
[int]$range1 = Read-Host "Enter the first limit";
[int]$range2 = Read-Host "Enter the last limit";
<#The for loop is setting the range of numbers#>
for ($i = $range1; $i -le $range2; $i++) {
    $temp = $i;
    $originalnumber = $i;
    $revnum = 0;
    <#The while loop is to check the reverse of each number #>
    while ($temp -ne 0) {
        $remainder = $temp % 10;
        $revnum = $revnum * 10 + $remainder;
        $temp = $temp / 10;
    }
    <#The if condition is to check whether the original number and reverse number is 
    equal to each other#>
    if ($originalnumber -eq $revnum) {
        Write-Host "$originalnumber is a palindrome number between $range1 and $range2" -ForegroundColor Green;
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$originalnumber is not a palindrome number" -ForegroundColor Red;
    }
}
```

```
OUTPUT:-
VERBOSE: This script is for checking Palindrome numbers between a range
Please enter the range of numbers
Enter the first limit: 10
Enter the last limit: 15
10 is not a palindrome number
11 is not a palindrome number
12 is not a palindrome number
13 is not a palindrome number
14 is not a palindrome number
15 is not a palindrome number
```

I was expecting numbers like 11 or 121 to return as Palindrome numbers.

Comment: It is probably easier to treath the numbers as strings, See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-palindromes/

Comment: Your `$revnum` always ends up to `[double]::PositiveInfinity` through faulty defined condition in `while` statement because `$temp = $temp / 10;` goes to zero after pretty much iterations…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex to get the reversed string for each number and just use the `-eq` operator to see if you have a palindrome or not.

See [Regular expression options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options)

```
# suppose these are the start and end range numbers
$range1 = 10
$range2 = 15

# then
for ($i = $range1; $i -le $range2; $i++) {
    # stringify the number by surrounding it with double quotes or use $i.ToString()
    $reverse = ([regex]::Matches("$i", '.', 'RightToLeft')).Value -join ''
    if ($i -eq $reverse) { "$i is a palindrome number" }
    else {"$i is NOT a palindrome number"}
}
```

Output:

```
10 is NOT a palindrome number
11 is a palindrome number
12 is NOT a palindrome number
13 is NOT a palindrome number
14 is NOT a palindrome number
15 is NOT a palindrome number
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the way you are checking the palindroms. Example for a specific number can be:

```
$number_example = 20
$array_number = $number_example.ToString().ToCharArray()
[array]::reverse($array_number)
$reverse_number =  -join($array_number)

# if the two values are equal then do what ever
$number_example.ToString() -eq $reverse_number
```

Source: [source page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-palindromes/)

Comment: Try : (10..20) | foreach { $num = $_.ToString(); $reverse = [string]::Join('',[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse($num)); if($num -eq $reverse) {Write-Host "palindrom : "$_}else {Write-Host "not palindrom : "$_}}

Answer (score 0):

See explanations in commented code:

```
# functions are better than prompting for user input (can be automated)
function Find-Palindromes([int]$From, [int]$To) {

    for ($i = $From; $i -le $To; $i++) { # walk through each number in the given range

        $numberString = $i.ToString() # palindromes are really about characters, not numbers

        $reversed = for($j = $numberString.Length - 1; $j -ge 0; $j--) { # index the string from last to first
            $numberString[$j] # stores to $reversed variable as a char array
        }

        if (-join $reversed -eq $numberString) { # joining the char array makes it a string to compare to the original
            $i # includes in the output
        }
    }
}

Find-Palindromes -from 1000 -to 5000
```